# Jquery - Determine if ajax request is form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to see if there was a way in Jquery to determine if an ajax request is a form submit.  The reason being is that I show a loading animation on AjaxStart() for .load calls to load a new page but don't want to show an animation on form submits.

Code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
     loadingdiv.show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
//this will happen FIRST
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) //or jQuery.post , nevermind
{
   //...  
   window.submitting=true;
   //...
});



 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
   if (window.submitting) ...
});
```